# how Telerik RadSpreadsheet can show grouping?

Tags: wpf, telerik, spreadsheet

I used RadSpreadsheet in wpf and made an excel like application, but there is a problem when I open excel files containing grouped cells.

[excel showing grouped cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKcpK.png)

[telerik can't show grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzTR9.png)

How can I show grouping in telerik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping is not supported in the UI of RadSpreadsheet control (see [Spreadsheet: Grouping (Outline)](https://feedback.telerik.com/wpf/1353784-spreadsheet-grouping-outline) feature request).

Still, such documents can be created, imported and exported, as the feature is supported in the document model ([Grouping | Telerik Document Processing](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radspreadprocessing/features/grouping)), e.g.:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(); 
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(); 
worksheet.Columns[0].SetOutlineLevel(1); 
worksheet.Columns[1, 2].SetOutlineLevel(2); 
worksheet.Columns[3].SetOutlineLevel(1);
```

Comment: tnx for answer. yes you are right, I found that there's no way to show grouping in RadSpreadSheet. This request is not complete anymore!